# Bootstrap dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form, and I'm trying to use a dropdown as a message displayer. When I focus out the input, the dropdown displays. The problem is that it closes right after showing.

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    <li class="dropdown list-unstyled">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button"data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            My message.
        </ul>
    </li>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#name').focusout(function () {
       $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    });
});
```

I couldn't figure out why it closes yet. Strange thing is that if I click outside and drag the mouse just a little before releasing it, the dropdown doesn't close.
Thanks!

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/syp7ynqm/

edit: the problem seems to be that the dropdown detects the outside click right after it shows, so it closes (as it should) but I would like to disable this function, only for this first click, so that on the focus out the message would be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just go with the show method. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/2khohoqn/).

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#name').focusout(function () {
       $('.dropdown-menu').show();
    });
});
```

And your html should look like the following because li should be a child of ul so you would want to go with the folling html.

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            My message.
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are not using the bootstrap feature, I'd like to use that because I wouldn't need to add any css. It's the closest answer though, if I don't get any other I'll go with this one. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so it is basically the same as using bootstraps but I have edited my answer to fully use bootstrap.  Also I have edited your html a bit just to make it correct as li is supposed to be a child of a ul and should not be outside of a ul element just to make it a correct markup.  But I included and updated fiddle as well so check out the fiddle again and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#name').focusout(function () {
       $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
    $(document).mousedown(function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    })
    
});
```

Comment: Actually not the same problem, I'm sorry. The problem of this one is that it doesn't close unless I click inside the input and then click outside again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the dropdown method use toggle to show or hide the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#name').focusin(function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
 });
 $('#name').focusout(function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
 });
});
```

This results in the dropdown showing up when the input is focused and disappearing when you click away.

Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e59xb38p/40/

Comment: The problem is that I want to display the message when I focus out. See this fiddle as answered to saikumaru, using toggle. Still not working. jsfiddle.net/syp7ynqm/8 I also eddited the question adding more info

Comment: So you want to display the message whenever the user is not focused in on the #name box ? Try timing out the display of the dropdown on focus out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var $dropDownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu');
    // displays as default
    $dropDownMenu.css("display", "block");

    $('#name')
    .focusin(function () {
       $dropDownMenu.css("display", "none");
    })
    .focusout(function () {
         $dropDownMenu.css("display", "block");
    });
});
```